# TagHelpers not working when assembly is dynamically loaded in ASP.NET core 2.1

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, razorengine

I'm using ASP.NET core 2.1. I load all the assemblies that have the Views dynamically from a **plugins** folder. I use the following code for that. The Views get loaded correctly.

```
services.AddMvc().
    AddRazorPagesOptions(o => o.AllowAreas = true).
    SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1).
    ConfigureApplicationPartManager(ConfigureApplicationParts);

private void ConfigureApplicationParts(ApplicationPartManager apm)
{
    var pluginsPath = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "Plugins");

    var assemblyFiles = Directory.GetFiles(pluginsPath, "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    foreach (var assemblyFile in assemblyFiles)
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyFile);

        if (assemblyFile.EndsWith(".Views.dll"))
        {
            apm.ApplicationParts.Add(new CompiledRazorAssemblyPart(assembly));
        }
        else
        {
            apm.ApplicationParts.Add(new AssemblyPart(assembly));
        }
    }
}
```

The views have some custom taghelpers.

The **_ViewImports.cshtml** file looks like

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, MyTagHelpers
```

The problem is that the custom tag helpers don't get loaded and gives an error:

> Error: Could not load file or assembly MyTagHelpers

The reason I get the error may be the Razor View Engine may be looking for the DLL in the **bin** folder of the main app and it can't find the DLL and gives this error.

What should I do in the startup to say the taghelpers are available in a DLL and can be loaded from there? Should I use [TagHelperFeatureProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.taghelpers.taghelperfeatureprovider?view=aspnetcore-2.1) to do it?

**UPDATE:** I moved the tag helpers to a separate DLL called **MyTagHelpers.Common** and dropped in the plugins folder. I'm not getting any assembly not found error anymore, but the tag helpers are not working.

Answer (score 2):

After 2 days trying to resolve this - please note - the 'assembly name' is the compiled (assembled?) .DLL name which would normally match the project name which may **not** match the namespace name/prefix!

So if your project name is not the same as the namespace as mine was, then the @addTagHelper reference is the project name which is being used to create the compiled .DLL - see your build output to check.

And therefore, this is also usually the same as the prefix for your .csproj file which is why the official documentation says to create a new app.